# Why Exception inside a method should be handled within the method itself and not outside?

Tags: exception, java

Consider a method() that throws some exception in its body.
Consider the following scenarios: 
Scenario 1:

```
{
  //..
  // ..
  method();    //Exception handled inside the method
  //..
  //..
}
```

In this case the exception should be handled within the method() itself.

Also consider this:
Scenario 2:

```
{
   //..
   //..
   try{
      method();   //Exception not handled with-in the method
      }
    catch(){}
   //..
   // ..
}
```

Why a situation like scenario 2 is not allowed? ie why it is forced that the exception should be handled within the method?

Comment: And who said so? You catch the exception only when you know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `throws` clause to your method and make it throw an `exception`, which can be handled, as mentioned in **Situation 2**. So its allowed, like this:-

```
void method() throws Exception{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both scenarios are allowed. The restriction (if that's the right term) that Java imposes is that the exception *must* be handled somewhere.

In the first scenario, the called method handles the exception itself - so there's no need for the try-catch in the calling method.

The second scenario is valid - but only if `method()` includes the `throws` declaration to indicate that the exception must be handled somewhere else.

```
void method() throws Exception
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed!
use as follows

```
public void method() throws ClassNotFoundException {
```

to catch a ClassNotFoundException.
(In most cases you should not throw a bare `Exception`, like other posters simplified)

Whether to chatch inside or outside is software design. There is no rule of thumb.
My experience is that catching outside leads to less complex code, which can be better unit tested .

Look for design pattern "last line of defense":
That means that in your top most class e.g in main() there is a  `catch (Exception ex) {`

which catches when no other method catched it. in that case you can log the exception and (try to) safely shut down your system. This is the last line of defense.
Note: spmetimes it also makes sense to `catch(Throweable th)`,

Comment: Google knows no "last line of defense" design pattern, at least nothing related to exception handling...

Comment: +1, although I am not convinced about this pattern, because it would not catch exceptions thrown for other threads. I think a better "last line of defense" would be to use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle exception using senario-2, then cannot map the exception to the actual one. i.e you cannot state it as per the code in block. So please handle the exception to the spot itself, so that you can specifically explain why the exception has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the idea is to throw early and catch late. Overall, you want to minimize exceptions you throw by simply making your logic "flow". But there are always situations which are tricky to handle, or obfuscate code too much, so it is worth ensuring the user understands the risks of using certain methods and handles them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Never trap [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) unless you really mean to. It almost always needs to be thrown.

This great question is actually a very important design decision. Getting this right is difficult and getting this right across an entire team is even more difficult. The answer to the question lies within your implementation. Does the error need to be immediately shown to the user? Do you have an auxiliary method to recover from the failure? Is the exception a fatal event?

Please do yourself a favor and never write an empty exception handler. You will be very happy to have put in a log.debug statement in there when things go awry. Other than that: learn what every exception means and respond to it in the most graceful way possible.

Comment: Huh? This doesn't even come close to answering the question. OP is asking why something doesn't work. And where did InterruptedException come into it???